# Selecting values of column whose instances share the same value in another column [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to make a (probably) simple query, given the following table:

[image: enter link description here]

I would like to get the values in nom_planta
which have the same value in nom_adob across all its instances (I'm not sure if instances is the correct word to use in this context).

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you looking to find the values that are common in the columns nom_planta and nom_adob ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the distinct values, use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct nom_planta
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to make sure a nom_planta has only one, distinct nom_planta value.

```
select nom_planta
from tablename
group by nom_planta
having count(distinct nom_planta) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you need. You need to group by nom_planta and keep only those which have just one distinct nom_adob associated.

```
SELECT
    nom_planta
FROM
    initial_table
GROUP BY
    nom_planta
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT nom_adob) = 1
```